# How to create a recursive join in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, recursive-query

I have a query with a bunch of left joins to get a hierarchal list of managers for an employee. I know snowflake has a recursive functionality but having trouble following. Does anyone know how something like this can be written recursively?

```
select
    d1.employee_id,
    d1.employee_id1,
    d1.employee_id2,
    d1.employee_id3,
    d2.employee_id1 as employee_id4,
    d2.manager_name as employee_id4_name,
    d3.employee_id1 as employee_id5,
    d3.manager_name as employee_id5_name,
    d4.employee_id1 as employee_id6,
    d4.manager_name as employee_id6_name,
    d5.employee_id1 as employee_id7,
    d5.manager_name as employee_id7_name
from employees d1
left join employees d2
on d1.employee_id3 = d2.employee_id
and d1.report_effective_date = d2.report_effective_date
left join employees d3
on d2.employee_id1 = d3.employee_id
and d2.report_effective_date = d3.report_effective_date
left join employees d4
on d3.employee_id1 = d4.employee_id
and d3.report_effective_date = d4.report_effective_date
left join employees d5
on d4.employee_id1 = d5.employee_id
and d4.report_effective_date = d5.report_effective_date
```

Edit with what I've tried - and from my understanding the way I want this formatted doesn't seem possible? I'm looking to get an individual's manager hierarchy but with each manager in a new column.

What I tried was like this, but it would give me the hierarchy in rows and would require that I have an anchored query filtered to someone.

```
with cte as (
  select
    employee_id,
    employee_name,
    employee_id1,
    manager_name
  from employees
  where employee_name = <name>
  
  union all

  select
    employee.employee_id,
    employee.employee_name,
    employee.employee_id1,
    employee.manager_name
  from employees
  join cte
  on employee.employee_id = cte.employee_id1
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: Recursive queries are documented extensively in the Snowflake documentation (and elsewhere) - so what have you tried and what specific issue are you facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you would get back rows instead of columns. You are also correct that you would need to anchor the query on someone, or some group. Consider, as an anchor, an employee that has no employee_id1 assigned (The top most person in the org, if I understand your data).

As for the "Data in rows" consider building a hierarchical path that you can split to an array or what-have-you:

```
with cte as (
  select
    employee_id as employee,
    employee_name,
    employee_id1 as manager,
    manager_name,
    CAST(employee_id AS VARCHAR(500)) as path,
    1 as depth
  from employees
  where employee_id1 IS NULL
  
  union all

  select
    employee.employee_id,
    employee.employee_name,
    employee.employee_id1,
    employee.manager_name,
    cte.path || '>' || employee.employee_id,
    cte.depth + 1
  from employees
  join cte
  on employee.employee_id = cte.employee_id1
)
select * from cte
```

Now you have the full path for the employee as well as the depth of that employee, which should help plenty.

Comment: Glad it was helpful. `path` and `depth` is something I add to nearly every recursive query I build. `Path` can be especially helpful to hold in a table as it allows you to query, in this case, every person that is aligned under a particular manager regardless of the level in the org of the employees or manager, with something as simple as `SELECT * FROM this_result_set WHERE path LIKE  '*45>*'`  "45" being the manager's id.